# How to boot someone off iTunes Remote Speakers

Tags: itunes, remote-access

There's a person playing the worst music through our speakers. How might I boot them off and take over?

Using Apple Airport Express and iTunes on mac

Answer (score 2):

Unplug or restart the AirPort (using the AirPort Utility).

Then, properly configure it: password protect the speakers (again, using AirPort Utility).